# Recharts cartesian grid - different style for vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: reactjs, recharts

What I would like to achieve is this:
[image]

How do I configure the CartesianGrid to have dashes on the horizontal axis and a solid line on the vertical axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no simple solution, based on configuration options. A hacky solution can be implemented by changing the grid lines at either ends: when they are created (the solution below) or after they are rendered - the grid line in the resulting svg may be accessed as `.recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal > line` and those lines need to have their `stroke-dasharray` properties altered.

So, a possible solution is to extend the class `CartesianGrid`. Below is a quick solution that only addresses the question as asked; one can extend that to a complex grid class that has different properties for the vertical and horizontal lines. The reference for that should come from the source code: [CartesianGrid.tsx](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/v2.5.0/src/cartesian/CartesianGrid.tsx).

The class that changes the `stroke-dasharray` for the vertical axis could be implemented as (tsx):

```ts
class CartesianGridNoDashVertical extends CartesianGrid {
  renderVertical(verticalPoints: number[]): JSX.Element {
    const element = super.renderVertical(verticalPoints);
    const lines = element.props.children.map((el: JSX.Element) =>
      React.cloneElement(el, { strokeDasharray: "0" })
    );
    return React.cloneElement(element, [], lines);
  }
}
```

and used instead of the standard grid element in the markup:

```
<LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}
  >
    <CartesianGridNoDashVertical strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <XAxis />
    <YAxis />    
</LineChart>
```

Here' a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-vxxbet?file=/src/App.tsx:1077-1585) forked from a standard recharts example.

Comment: @karlrez expanding on this great answer, it's really easy to do via css (as kikon mentioned). Here is an example:
`.recharts-cartesian-grid-vertical > line { stroke-dasharray: 0.1; }`